# The correct way of the authentication and authorization of a JAX-WS Web Service?

Tags: web-services, glassfish, authorization, jax-ws

I have trouble with implementing the authorization of a JAX-WS Web Service. I'm developing a Swing application that can be connected to a Java EE application via a JAX-WS web service. Users can log in to the server with the Swing application, and can download user specific data from the server. It is important that a logged user couldn't download data that belongs to other users.

My problem is that `jaxwsContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()` returns with "ANONYMOUS". I read similar questions on this portal, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Actually I have this:

server side:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebService
public class SampleWSEJB extends AbstractSampleEJB implements ISampleWSLocal, ISampleWSRemote {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext jaxwsContext;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username = jaxwsContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }

    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public UserDataVO logInUser() {
        return SampleServerServices.getInstance().logInUser(getEm(), this.getUsername());
    }

...
...

}
```

Client side:

Some classes I generated with the wsimport tool (ImportedSampleWSEJB, UserDataVO etc...)

relevant client code:

```
private static ImportedSampleWSEJB importedEJB;

public UserDataVO logInUser(String username, String password) {
    Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)ImportedSampleWSEJB.importedEJB).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
    return importedEJB.logInUser();
}
```

I use "file" as security realm, and I created some test user in glassfish 3.1.

Anybody any idea how to fix it?

Comment: this may be related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975070/how-to-enable-spring-security-for-apache-cxf-jax-ws.  also look into Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic authentication(http header) or you can use UserName Token (part of WS- Security). User Name token will be going in SOAP Header rather than http header.