# Spring boot + Apache CXF for soap web service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, cxf

I have been working on the spring boot. I followed this example and try to create a simple soap web service using [this sample code](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jaxws_spring_boot).
After following this whole sample. I faced an issue when I run my application. Following is the stack trace of the error.

```
2017-09-09 20:06:59.883 ERROR 7302 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.posts.PostApplication.main(PostApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 23 common frames omitted

2017-09-09 20:06:59.884  INFO 7302 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6dbb137d: startup date [Sat Sep 09 20:06:58 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-09 20:06:59.885  WARN 7302 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6dbb137d: startup date [Sat Sep 09 20:06:58 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:999) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.posts.PostApplication.main(PostApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

2017-09-09 20:06:59.886 ERROR 7302 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6dbb137d: startup date [Sat Sep 09 20:06:58 PKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.posts.PostApplication.main(PostApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:818)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:804)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:790)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.posts.PostApplication.main(PostApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I wanted to create a simple soap web service in spring boot. I am using the apache cfx for this purpose.

Here is the pom.xml file.

Comment: It seems that there is an error with the `pom.xml` dependencies, could you share the `pom.xml` of your project?  I create a similar project but I had to change `pom.xml` accordingly to the current versions from https://start.spring.io/

Comment: https://github.com/mumarm45/springboot/blob/master/pom.xml. Here is the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean` was removed from Spring version `1.5.x` .  The error is caused by the version of org.apache.cxf .. cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws `<version>3.1.7</version>` because it is depending on the `org.spri...embedded.ServletRegistrationBean` removed from SB `1.5.x`.

Just update `org.apache.cxf  cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws` dependency to the version that is compatible with SB `1.5.x`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Update the maven dependencies and you will see that the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception will not show again.

[Here is one example about Spring Boot + Apache cxf](https://github.com/faustocdiaz/cxf-demo)

**EDIT**

In order to secure your cxf Servlet one possible solution is to use http basic authentication, spring boot will auto-configure security filter chain in order to perform authentication before the cxf servlet is consumed, just follow this steps:

Add spring security dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

As soon as you add Spring security dependencies spring boot will automatically secures all the http endpoints with http basic authentication.  If you need to customize this configuration, here is an example:

Create a `@Configuration` class that extends from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override configure method in order to configure authentication and authorization process: like this

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        //credentials and roles to use
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("soapuser").password("secret").roles("ADMIN");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        //this configuration define that every request is authorized only to Admin roles and authenticated users.
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()

                //this configuration define an http basic authentication
                .and().httpBasic()

                //disable csfr
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Finally I would recommend always perform http basic authentication over https, it can be accomplished through `application.properties` configuration:

```
server.port=9443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
```

In this example the application will run over https on 9443 port `https://localhost:9443/`

This post lists other alternatives to secure apache cxf through spring security [Spring Security Apache cxf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975070/how-to-enable-spring-security-for-apache-cxf-jax-ws).  I also update the the git repo to show an example of how implement spring security with spring boot and apache cxf.

Comment: Thanks, Did you ever secure the soap api using spring security? Any suggestion you can give.

Comment: Hi, I just add new information related to security, also you can view an example in the git repo.

Comment: basically, I wanted to secure my soap api using token based authentication. Can't just have the security enable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incompatibility problem, happens if you are using spring-boot 1.5 and later. You need to use the latest version of cxf:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.1.2'
```

This version solved my problem:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
```

Answer bsed in Grails project.